# QIntValidator returns Intermediate in valid input

Tags: c++, qt, qvalidator

I have a `QIntValidator(int min, int max, QWidget* parent)` set-up, but it returns `QValidator::Intermediate` with inputs that are between min and max (i.e. valid).

I'm using this QIntValidator to check if an input, an integer number, is between the minimum and maximum stabilished. If not, the input is discarded, returning the editor to its previous value.

Imagine that the minimum value is 1 and the maximum is 2147483648. If the user inputs, for example, the number 3, it returns QValidator::Intermediate. This seems like and odd behavior. Any ideas why is this happening?

```
QLineEdit *lnEdt = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(item);
QString valData = lnEdt->text(); // "3"
int nRow = ui->listWidget->currentRow();

if(editor == QVariant::Int) //the type of input, in this case, it's true
{
    qDebug() << minimum; //1
    qDebug() << maximum; //2147483648
    QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(minimum.toInt(), maximum.toInt());
    int pos = 0;
    qDebug() << validator->validate(valData, pos); // QValidator::Intermediate
    if(validator->validate(valData, pos) != QValidator::Acceptable)
    //it falls in this condition, rejecting the input 
    //and setting the editor text to its previous value.
        ui->listWidget->item(nRow)->setText(currentSelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: ok, do you even have a question??

Comment: Sorry, I got so caught up in the "guided" question making that I forgot the most important. Anyway, this seems an odd behavior, and I would appreciate some thoughts on why the validator rejects a valid input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html says that this is intended behaviour (length of input is less than length of maximum).

Comment: You're totally right. A little, but crucial, piece of documentation that escaped my sight. Thank you!

"Values consisting of a number of digits equal to or less than the max value are considered intermediate. This is intended because the digit that prevents a number from being in range is not necessarily the last digit typed. This also means that an intermediate number can have leading zeros."